# re-internilizing a symbol from namespace-mapped-symbols

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I'm not sure if the question title is appropriate but here is what I wonder:

From the repl, I wanted to get the list of bindings defined in the current module. After some searching this seemed like a good solution:

```
(define (racket-symbols-set)
  (list->set (namespace-mapped-symbols (module->namespace 'racket))))
(define (namespace-symbols-set)
  (list->set (namespace-mapped-symbols)))
(define (module-bindings)
  (set->list (set-subtract
              (namespace-symbols-set)
              (racket-symbols-set))))
```

so, calling (module-bindings) returns a list of symbols. But if I try to call a symbol from that result, such as doing ((first (module-bindings))), I get a "application: not a procedure" error although the first symbol is a procedure.

How do I call the corresponding procedure of that symbol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look up the value of a namespace variable using [`namespace-variable-value`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Namespaces.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._namespace-variable-value%29%29). And since your `namespace-symbols-set` just uses the current namespace, which is also the default namespace for `namespace-variable-value`, using it is very simple.

For example, to invoke the procedure associated with the first item in the list returned by your `module-bindings` procedure:

```
((namespace-variable-value (car (module-bindings))))
```

Alternatively, specify your preferred namespace as the fourth argument of the `namespace-variable-value` call.

Comment: Good point, Chris! Seems I will read the racket reference chapter 14 soon.

Answer (score 1):

You need to evaluate that symbol in order for it to return the corresponding procedure.

```
> (define (foo) 'bar)
> (eval 'foo)
#<procedure:foo>
> ((eval 'foo))
'bar
```

Hence in your case

```
((eval (car (module-bindings))))
```

will call the first procedure of the list returned by `module-bindings`.